# CSVファイルを、含まれているデータを利用したaタグ入りのCSVファイルへ変換したい

Tags: csv

下記のようなCSVファイルを、aタグ入りのCSVファイルへ変換したいのですが、どういう方法がありますか？
PHPやJavaScriptやテキスト処理などでできますか？

**元データcsv**

```
日時1,説明1,URL1,文字列1,,,
日時2,説明2,URL2,文字列2,,,
```

↓
**作成したいデータcsv**

```
日時1,<a href="URL1">説明1</a>,文字列1,,,
日時2,<a href="URL2">説明2</a>,文字列2,,,
```

↓
**最終的にHTML出力したい**

---

試してみたこと
libreoffice calc でCSVファイルを読み込み、空の 2 列目を挿入後、そこへ 3 列目と 4 列目から取得したデータを追加しようとしたのですが、エラーになりました。
具体的には、数式入力ボックスに

```
=<a href="D1:D1048576">C1:C1048576</a>
```

と入力してみたのですが、予め指定された数式以外は受け付けないらしく数式エラーとなりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

各要素の文字列内にカンマやダブルクォート、`\r\n`, `\n` が含まれていないことが前提。(その点を考慮すると PHP や JavaScript の方がよさそうですが)

```bash
$ awk -F, -vOFS=, '{$2=sprintf("<a href=\"%s\">%s</a>", $3, $2);for(i=3;i<NF;i++) $i=$(i+1);NF--}1' data.csv
日時1,<a href="URL1">説明1</a>,文字列1,,,
日時2,<a href="URL2">説明2</a>,文字列2,,,
```

Comment: 期待通り動作しました

Answer (score 1):

LibreOffice Calc での例:

| 説明 | URL | 結果 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| スタックオーバーフロー | `https://ja.stackoverflow.com` | `=CONCATENATE("<a herf=",B1,">",A1,"</a>")` |

Comment: 試してみたのですが、式の結果ではなく、書式がそのまま表示されてしまいました……